# How to validate price in input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have an input (it's text input) where users can set up the price.
The problem is, that users can sometimes set up the price like this:

```
9
9.99
9,99
$9.99
```

What's the best way to validate this input? I am running the app on Heroku (= PostgreSQL database), the data type column is **decimal**.

Comment: What are the accepted price values for your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below. It matches all you examples.

```
validates :price, :presence => true,
            :format => { :with => /^(\$)?(\d+)(\.|,)?\d{0,2}?$/ }
```

Answer (score 2):

Rails 4 complains about using $ and ^, so use:

```
validates :price, :presence => true, 
  :format => { :with => /\A(\$)?(\d+)(\.|,)?\d{0,2}?\z/ }
```

Just trying to save people time ;-)